# Suggestion for Permanent SnackBar Like Message Angular Mat

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to have a floating message box on a component just like how the matsnackbar looks. There is no way to make the snackbar stay indefinite and setting the dismissal time really high is not professional. Also, I don't want them to have the option of dismissing it.

Does anyone have a easy-implement-solution for this?

I searched many times for a like question on google and not much came up fitting a permanent component overlay for angular mat.

Screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9c4M.png

Comment: maybe you can take some ideas from this libary: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier.  it's not a snackbar per se, but it has similar functionaility.  mainly it has a timed option, as well as a click to dismiss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this [[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar)] you can set the autohide to 0. Might be what you're after?

```
    config.duration = this.setAutoHide ? this.autoHide : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @JonjoJefferson